# r.mapcalc doesn't create anything

Tags: qgis

I have to calculate a NDVI raster with 2 Landsat maps.
The formula is as following :

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't show up in my layer list and when I try to export it from GRASS via r.out.gdal.gtiff, I get this:

[image: img]

My colleagues also get this message but they don't have the "Unable to create dataset using driver" part, and it works well on their computer.

I used both Qgis 2.12 Lyon and 2.8.3 Wien and it does the same thing. 
Can you guys help me to fix this please ?

Comment: Can you ensure that you've set `g.region rast=ETM4` and post the output of `r.info ETM4`?

Comment: Here is what i get : http://hpics.li/79e48d2

Answer (score 1):

this is probably an issue with the pixel type. Multiplying with 1.0 yield a float, but after the division. Try this :

```
r.mapcalc "ndvi=float(etm4 - etm3) / (etm4 + etm3)"
```

Comment: I've just tried your formula but sadly it's still the same.

Comment: and with the float() also in denominator ? can you display the data in qgis gui? have you tried gdal_calc.py ? Without the data we can't help more as it looks ok.

Comment: the second float doesn't make it work, I can't visualize NDVI raster in Qgis as it says it's not a supported raster format. Also, gdal_calc.py doesn't work : it says no program is associated to this action and asks me to install some program